# How to change view of ManyToManyField in template?

Tags: django

[It's ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABZ2e.png)

What can I do to see there the body of this field? There must be a values of Size object, but not "Size object (id)"

I have Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Good(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    Size = models.ManyToManyField('Size')

    def _str_(self):
        return self.Name

class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length = 150)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.size
```

This is my forms.py

```
class GoodGet(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good_Get
        Size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Good.objects.all())
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, good_id1=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if good_id1 is not None:
            obj = Good.objects.filter(id = good_id1)
            for good in obj:
                good_sizes = good.Size.all()
            self.fields['Size'].queryset = good_sizes
```

So, I want the user to choose the size from the list of Good's sizes, but he can't see what size does he choose.
I think I need to do something with my database, needn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *two* consecutive underscores in [**`__str__`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), not <s>`_str_`</s>, like:

```
class Good(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Size = models.ManyToManyField('Size')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size
```

"*Magic objects*" have, as the [PEP-8 documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) says, two consecutive leading and trailing underscores:

> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.